# SQL Server cannot build connection string to db

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection, database-connection

I tried the following in SQL Server Management Studio; I can connect and run query, but not from my project

```
string s = "Server=LAPTOP-7J47C5JA\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;";

string queryString =   "SELECT * from tbclienti";

cn = new SQLConnection(s);

// Create the Command and Parameter objects.
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, cn);

cn.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Text = reader[0].ToString();
    label1.Text = reader[1].ToString()+ " " + reader[2].ToString();
}

reader.Close();
cn.Close();
```

Comment: what exactly happens, any error ?

Comment: it comes a window with a list of processes., It'not proerly an an error

Comment: Lets try first connection string. Is it connecting to db ?

string s = @"Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test;Integated Security=SSPI;";

Comment: using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(s))
{
    try {
      cn.Open();
   }catch(Exception ex) {
  }
}

Comment: it gives error the name cn does not exist in the context windowsfromapp2

Comment: ok i removed my code and used only yours and there are no erors.but says System.ArgumentException: 'keyword 'integated security' not supported.'

Comment: Sorry my typo, Integrated Security, try code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted here whole code what could look like. Try it now.

```
    string s = @"Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

    using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(s))
    {
        string queryString = "SELECT * from tbclienti";

        try
        {    
          cn.Open();
          // Create the Command and Parameter objects.
          SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, cn);
          SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
          while (reader.Read())
          {
             Text = reader[0].ToString();
             label1.Text = reader[1].ToString()+ " " + reader[2].ToString();

           }
           reader.Close();
         }
         catch(Exception ex) 
         {
             // see if error appear
         }
         finally
         {
           cn.Close();
         }
    }
```

Comment: THANKS NOW IT WORKS: i ONLY ADDED @ IN FRONT OF THE CONNECTION STRING

Comment: Ah those backslashes :). Im glad it worked. If you dont put @ you need two backslashes like \\